# You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle. What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle
>
> Or helping you to navigate the alphabet
>
> I might even be like a small explosion.
>
> But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

What am I?

Hint #1:

> Sprinting could be by itself, the circle might be on the subject of something instead and it would still fit.

Hint #2:

> You don't have to navigate the alphabet very far.

Hint #3:

> It's more about the sound, really.

Hint #4:

> Think about another term for "proving that you have knowledge of something".

Hint #5:

> Consider that my favourite way of creating a puzzle is to use synonyms of things that relate to the subject indirectly: for example, for "leaves" I might say "If you want to be green, move away from the room." Think about synonyms for words I've used in each line, especially line 1.

Hint #6:

> Lines 1 and 3 refer to colloquial names for the object, rather than the object itself. Line 2 is about an idiom that describes what the object does. Line 4 refers to something you need to do in order to use one.

Comment: Noticing a few downvotes. Not that I don't encourage criticism of puzzles you don't like, but I'd appreciate an explanation if the downvoters don't mind. :)

Comment: -1, I think a riddle ought to stand alone and be solvable without hints. That said, your riddle is clearly too broad without hints (16 answers as of this comment), and hints should generally not be posted until ~24 hours after posting the riddle. Many people in the Americas, for example, have been asleep since your riddle was posted and woke up to see 6 ham-fisted hints already added.

Comment: @JohnClifford Now that we have the answer I think the puzzle is way to vague. As I get from the comments you expected a special word for every line in the puzzle but also never really made clear that you do so(until the very last hint implies it). I see this as poor execution. Just a personal opinion, it's not bad but I dislike it, thus the down vote.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for explaining the downvote. I didn't think it was that vague but then I came up with it so I'm naturally biased. I do think calling the hints ham-fisted was slightly uncalled for, but I appreciate the sentiment and will take the feedback into account if I post again.

Comment: @John Clifford I took the potential vagueness as an incentive for a second try. Hoping it is not disallowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it:

> A car

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> Set of wheels would be another name for a car.

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> Mobile?  Children use mobiles to learn the alphabet.

I might even be like a small explosion.

> A car can sound like a bomb when running poor or be called a ticking bomb if someone thought it was unreliable.

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> You need to pass a license test in order to drive, proving your knowledge.

Edited for further attempts at detail.

Comment: Correct answer, but only the last line explanation is right. Keep thinking about it.

Comment: If the comments on my answer are any indicator, then I'm seeing a potential connection, but not how it fits the lines of the riddle.

Comment: For line 1, consider something you might affectionately call one. Line 3 is something you'd call an old one. For line 2, think "It helps you ____".

Comment: (2. get from A to B. 3. banger)

Comment: Correct, Gareth. :)

Comment: Cool!  Never would've thought of banger.

Comment: "banger" sounds like a probably UKian term. I don't think I've heard it before about an old [spoiler redacted].

Comment: Cool. This is where being ESL is a disadvantage. I know the words and terms, but I didn't / wouldn't think of it.

Comment: You can call a car a "run-around" (line 1).

Comment: The third clue should have hinted at **why** it might "be like a small explosion". Also, as a life-long U.S. citizen, I have never heard the word "banger" except when a parody of a Brit is making an innuendo about sausages.

Comment: I think it's interesting that there are so many ways to draw connections between the lines and the answer.
I think it's because the lines are inadvertently describing literal components of the answer, from which many idioms are also likely influenced.

Answer (score 9):

I think it is...

> OSX's loading icon?? (loading-circle, looks like a lollipop) :P

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> yeah, it sprinting in a circle, and unstoppable.

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> Sometimes it will appears when you are using old computer, to connect to the alphabet (Google) website.

I might even be like a small explosion.

> when it appears, that means you need to wait for a while, or the program is being crashed. You will lose your temper of it, feeling mad just like a small explosion.

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> The icon only noticed you need to wait...... shall we care about it?!

I think the answer may be incorrect but just for fun. :)

Comment: I kinda wish that were the answer just because of the thought that must have been involved to fit that with the lines of the riddle, but unfortunately your thinking is correct and the answer isn't. :)

Comment: Spoilers are `>!`, BTW.

Comment: @John Clifford I got this idea since my computer crashed once this morning. :'(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. :(

Answer (score 7):

What am I?

> A song

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> When you got a song stuck in your head you may say it sprints in a circle since you always repeat a certain phrase.

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> I am from Germany and we have a little song to remember the Alphabet(I still sing it in my head when navigating the alphabet) don't know if there is something similar for English speaking folks.

I might even be like a small explosion.

> Certain very good songs can give you very intense feelings, like a small explosion of feelings (also consider eargasm)

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> Weak guess: You have to prove that you know a song by humming it's melody

Comment: Not correct, but again a good guess! I'll add a hint or two to the OP.

Comment: Yes, we have an "Alphabet Song" in the States.  The tune is adapted from the opening melody of Haydn's "Surprise Symphony".  The children's song "Twinkle, Twinkle, Little Star" uses the same tune.

Answer (score 5):

Is it the letter?

> C

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> The s in **s**printing is almost read like the letter c itself, c as the s sound in many words. C is also almost a circle.

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> It is a letter of the alphabet

I might even be like a small explosion.

> caboom! [(c is read like K when the word starts with ca)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/how-can-i-tell-whether-c-should-be-pronounced-like-s-or-like-k)

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> [To confirm](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/to-show-or-agree-that-something-is-true)

Comment: Was exactly thinking about this one!

Comment: Good try, but no.

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> A star

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle:

> Stars orbit the earth

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet:

> The ABCs is the same tune as Twinkle Twinkle Little Star

I might even be like a small explosion:

> Stars often explode

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless:

> A stretch, but scientists have to prove the existence of new stars found in space.

Comment: No cigar I'm afraid.

Comment: There are no stars that 'orbit the earth' exactly...  Nice alphabet and explosion connections though. +1

Answer (score 3):

I think it's:

> Thought(s)

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> Thoughts running through your head.

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> You need to think about what you say. Especially when learning a new language.

I might even be like a small explosion.

> Thought overload. Sudden insight. Anger, hate, ...

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> Iffy on this one but: When discussing your thoughts, people will appreciate them more if they are truthful/founded in facts.

Comment: Another good answer, but not even close to what I'm looking for. Keep trying! :) If I get another incorrect guess I'll add a hint.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Alpha α

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> denoting a position within a particular sphere OR It is used to denote the area underneath a normal curve in statistics to denote significance level

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> First letter in alphabet

I might even be like a small explosion

> a particle physics experiment at CERN

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless

> not sure.

Since I belong to field of science, I came up with these assertions.

Comment: For the answer to be this I would have to be significantly smarter than I actually am.

Comment: Another hint is required.

Comment: I'm trying to think of one that won't immediately give away what it is.

Comment: Just added hint #6, see how you get on with that.

Answer (score 3):

Now the answer is found, let my add:

> A (wedding) ring

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> Ring can be a colloquial term for a circle. "The circle might be on the subject (of something instead) and it would still fit": it's good when rings fit your fingers. Very often, one sees persons rotating the ring around their fingers.

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> A ring is [a ring of Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Ring). But also Å, [a A with a smaller o above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85), a letter common in Scandinavian alphabets. Danish and Norwegian places Å as the last letter in the alphabet, you have to navigate through the alphabet to find it. But it is sometimes written "Aa" which put it at the beginning of dictionaries in countries not using this convention. Who were better navigators that the Vikings? The name of the loved one inside, or letters of your name are often found in wedding rings.

I might even be like a small explosion.

> After an explosion, you can have ringing ears. Love can be an explosion, and sadly marriage can explode

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> This rings a bell to me. When I gave a ring to my belle, my vows  proved that I knew the correct words, and  I knew her enough  (regardless of anything that could happen),  for better for worse, for richer for poorer... Wedding is something you need to do in order to use a wedding ring.

[leftover: initial answer for the record]

> Blast

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> A [ten-minute blast on a treadmill](http://www.muscleandfitness.com/workouts/workout-tips/10-minute-treadmill-blast). Prisoners on a treadmill used to walk in circle, fitness prisoners now run on belts (my weakest part)

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> [BLAST(Basic Local Alignment Search Tool)](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi)  is a technique to decrypt genome bricks A, T, G, C

I might even be like a small explosion.

> Blast is ok here (although it could be a huge explosion too)

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> I knew you. A blast from the past, you are a person who evokes a sense of nostalgia.

Comment: Some solid logic there, but not what I'm after. :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> the letter 'O'?

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> O is a circle

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> It's a letter

I might even be like a small explosion.

> 'Boom' is a short explosion word with two 'o's

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> 'Prove' has an 'o' in it

Comment: It is not, but good guess!

Answer (score 2):

Might it be:

> Alliteration?

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle:

> "Sprinting" and "circle" begin with the same sound (although the letters are different)

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet:

> The alphabet song is full of similar sounds

I might even be like a small explosion:

> "Alliteration" sounds like "A little detonation"?

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless:

> Not sure about this one. You have to explicitly use similar sounding letters to prove you know alliteration perhaps?

Comment: Incredibly inventive answer, but nowhere near it I'm afraid. :)

Answer (score 2):

Might it be:

> Bingo the dog?

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle:

> Dogs sometimes sprint in circles

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet:

> B-I-N-G-O like in the song

I might even be like a small explosion:

> Shouting 'Bingo!' at a Bingo game

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless:

> You have to call a dog by it's name to gain it's attention?

Comment: Can't say this one had crossed my mind while I was writing the riddle, but good guess! I'll add a couple more hints.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a computer mouse wheel? I can't describe it according to the question, but I am making a guess at it.

Comment: It is not. You can make a spoiler by putting >! before the line, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> The Brain?

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> Sometimes the brain spins around a thought or an idea but comes to no conclusion

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> Well, a bit too obvious, but you need it to remember the alphabet

I might even be like a small explosion.

> Having thought ravage through your mind can also be as loud and chaotic as an explosion

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> I genuinely have no idea how to fit that in^^

Comment: Hmm, realised it's more of a thought what I am describing, which was already posted..

Comment: Yes it is basically the same just with a different base. You can always try to come up with another answer, though!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is highly likely to be wrong, but it almost fits:

> [RC Cola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_Cola)

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> "RC" stands for Royal Crown; the Triple Crown is a series of horse-races where they indeed sprint in circles.

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> R and C are letters.

I might even be like a small explosion.

> It's a kind of "Pop".

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> Alright.. got me here. Something about opening the can?

Comment: Cryptic hint: In one way, part of your answer is the closest one there's been yet.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the explosion part; I actually worked backwards from thinking about explosion synonyms and got to this ridiculous place :)

Comment: When I say "Part of your answer" I mean the answer itself, not your explanations of the lines.

Comment: Then the explosion part still could be correct, if the last word of my answer is right ;)

Comment: Who said it was the last word? ;)

Comment: If it's the 2 letters, I see how they relate to the chosen answer, but not the lines of the poem (other than the "alphabet" line but that's really a weak connection)

Comment: I only meant that "RC" was connected to the answer, but your line interpretations weren't included. :)

Answer (score 1):

> ## $\Huge\text{Time}$

You may consider me to be sprinting in a circle

> Some scientists consider time to be circular

Or helping you to navigate the alphabet

> Saying the alphabet letters needs some time

I might even be like a small explosion.

> Big Bang.

But you'll have to prove that you know me regardless.

> Time is money (If you're smart ;) )!!

Answer (score -1):

Is the answer

> Revolution?

I'm just thinking and I also couldn't explain. I'm just guessing.

Comment: It's not that, no.